# Can't get running total to work

Tags: java, cumulative-sum

```
if(e.getSource() == register)
  {

     String registerIndex = coursesAvailable.getSelectedValue().toString();
     for(int i = 0; i < cTitle.length; i++)
     {
        double runningTotal = 0;

        if(cTitle[i].equals(registerIndex))
        {
           runningTotal += cPrice[i];

           cSeatsAvail[i] = cSeatsAvail[i] - 1;
           seatsAvailable.setText(String.valueOf(cSeatsAvail[i]));

           courseSelected.replaceSelection(cTitle[i] + " === $" + cPrice[i] + "\n");
           total.setText("Total: $" + runningTotal);
           break;
        }
        else
        {
           continue;
        }
     }
  }
```

Code for a "register" button. When you click it, whatever college course you have selected in a JList, it shows the course title and price in the courseSelected text area and your running total in the total text field. Problem is, my runningTotal doesn't add the values together and it seems to just replace the value in the total text field with the price of the new course.

Comment: `double runningTotal = 0` -> outside for-loop?

Comment: Your last sentence is rather impolite, don't you think?

Comment: could you explain what is registerIndex, and the logic of your tests ?

Comment: @Bathsheba I totally agree with you about OP's manner. But I don't see it as a reason for voting to close. It's more a reason for editing the post (and deleting the not needed paragraphs). Or am I wrong?

Comment: With registerIndex, I'm getting the selected index within the JList and converting it to a String so I can compare it in the if statement.

Comment: You've both written that last edit and accepted the answer at roughly the same time. What gives, does it work now or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently you **reset** runningTotal inside the loop - so it will not work:

```
for(int i = 0; i < cTitle.length; i++)
  {
    double runningTotal = 0; // Resets every iteration!!!
```

Try moving it outside the loop:

```
double runningTotal = 0; //Init once before the loop !
for(int i = 0; i < cTitle.length; i++)
  {
```

Comment: In what way? What is expected but not happening?

Comment: @Jan The running total just stays the same in the total text field. I tried getting runningTotal to show in a message box thinking there might be something wrong with the total text field but it's the same issue, it just replaces the previous price with the new one.

Comment: In that case runningTotal should be even farther out - remove from ActionListener and make it member variable of your class.

Answer (score 2):

replace this,

```
for(int i = 0; i < cTitle.length; i++)
     {
        double runningTotal = 0;
```

by

```
 double runningTotal = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < cTitle.length; i++)
     {
```